# Error in object[seq_len(ile)] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to convert an rmd file to pdf using render statement.

```
render("MiningReport.Rmd", "pdf_document",output_dir = "C:/ProjectSocial/Reports/Twitter/Maybelline")
```

I am getting an error as below

```
Quitting from lines 109-113 (MiningReport.Rmd) 
Error in object[seq_len(ile)] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

This looks very strange to me because when I knit the Rmd file then is no such error and the pdf report is generated successfully and when I try to do the same using render statement it gives error. Can anyone please explain what's going on ? Below is the code chunk where the error creeps in

````
```{r assoc ,echo=F,message=FALSE}
library(tm)
findAssocs(myTdm,df$term[1:10],0.5)
```
````

When I remove the above chunk then the same error occurs for the next chunk of code. Below is my Rmd file. I am reading in tweets stored in files present in the directory specified.

````
```{r computedate,echo = FALSE}
date1 <-format(Sys.Date() - 7,"%B %d")
date2 <-format(Sys.Date() - 1,"%B %d, %Y")

```

# This report has been created on twitter data from `r date1` to `r date2`.
# Analysis of Tweets
## Below we can see the most frequent words.

```{r frequent,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE,cache=TRUE}

setwd("C:/ProjectSocial/Data/TwitterData/Maybelline")

library(devtools)
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(graph)
library(Rgraphviz)
library(wordcloud)
library(topicmodels)
library(data.table)
library(fpc)
library(igraph)
library(xlsx)
library(stringr)

tweets.df<-data.frame(text=character(),favorited=character(),favoriteCount=numeric(),replyToSN=character(),
                created=as.POSIXct(character()),truncated=character(),replyToSID=character(),id=character(),replyToUID=character(),statusSource=character(),screenName=character(),retweetCount=numeric(),
isRetweet=character(),retweeted=character(),longitude=character(),latitude=character(),stringsAsFactors =F)
i<-1
while(i<=7){
  since<-Sys.Date()-i
  file<-read.xlsx2(file=paste("Maybelline",since,".xlsx",sep=""), 1,colClasses = c(rep("character",2),
  "numeric","character","POSIXct",rep("character",6),"numeric",rep("character",4)),   stringsAsFactors=F)

  tweets.df<-rbind(tweets.df,file)
  i<-i+1
}

j<-1
HashTagsList<-c()
HashTags<-str_extract_all(tweets.df$text,"#\\S+")
HashTags<-HashTags[!HashTags %in% c("character(0)")]

while (j<=length(HashTags)){

  HashTagsList<-c(HashTagsList,HashTags[[j]])
  j<-j+1
}
HashTagsList<- gsub("#", "", HashTagsList) 
HashTagsList<-unique(HashTagsList)
HashTagsList<-gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", HashTagsList)

k<-1
HandleTagsList<-c()
HandleTags<-str_extract_all(tweets.df$text,"@\\S+")
HandleTags<-HandleTags[!HandleTags %in% c("character(0)")]
while (k<=length(HandleTags)){

  HandleTagsList<-c(HandleTagsList,HandleTags[[k]])
  k<-k+1
}

HandleTagsList<- gsub("@", "", HandleTagsList) 
HandleTagsList<-unique(HandleTagsList)
HandleTagsList<-gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", HandleTagsList)

tweets.df$text<-gsub("#\\S+", "", tweets.df$text)
tweets.df$text<-gsub("@\\S+", "", tweets.df$text)

Tweets.df<-subset(tweets.df,isRetweet=="FALSE")
Tweets.df$text<-gsub("[^[:alpha:] ]", " ", Tweets.df$text)
Tweets.df$text<-tolower(Tweets.df$text)

myCorpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(Tweets.df$text))
myStopwords<-c(stopwords("english"),"maybelline","https","like","bring","make","thought","please","maybe",
               "know","just","want","wearing","really","last","better","best","first")
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,removeWords,myStopwords)
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,removeWords,HashTagsList)
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,removeWords,HandleTagsList)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
myTdm<-TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(wordLengths=c(4,13)))
freq.Terms<- findFreqTerms(myTdm,lowfreq=20)
termFrequency <- rowSums(as.matrix(myTdm))
termFrequency <- subset(termFrequency, termFrequency>=20)
df <- data.frame(term=names(termFrequency), freq=termFrequency,stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- df[order(-df$freq),] 
rownames(df) <- NULL
print(head(df,50), row.names = FALSE)
df<-head(df,40)
ggplot(df,aes(x=term,y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + xlab("Terms") +ylab("Count") +coord_flip()

```

## Below we can find all the words which are associated with the top 10 most frequent words and having correlation > 0.5.

```{r assoc ,echo=F,message=FALSE}

library(tm)
findAssocs(myTdm,df$term[1:10],0.5)

```
````

Any help appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Please attempt to provide some sort of minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we can run to re-create the error. This will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Who is `df` in your workspace? `df$term` throws the same error here, `df` is a R builtin function also.

Comment: @ Fernando Why it gives no error while knitting the file? df is just the name of the dataframe. The render statement was working perfectly for a few days and today suddenly it gave an error

Comment: Maybe your `df` is out of scope? Try `df = NULL` at the top of your file.

Comment: ok so the issue is resolved. The error was coming because I used echo=F instead of echo=FALSE

Comment: hi @Abhinav THANK YOU for posting this. I've had the same issue for weeks and haven't been able to make sense of it. that fix worked. I'm not sure why it was causing the problem, however but i appreciate this post!! can you answer your own question?

Comment: Hi @L Wasser                                                                                                      Here is why F (or T) is a symbol (see ?is.symbol to know what a symbol is):

> str(alist(warning = F))
List of 1
 $ warning: symbol F
> str(alist(warning = FALSE))
List of 1
 $ warning: logi FALSE

Comment: Can you accept your comment as the answer?  I almost gave up on this because there wasn't an answer but that is indeed the fix.

Comment: @RyanHaunfelder How do I do that? I don't know. Can you tell me?

Comment: Just rewrite your comment as an answer and you should be able to accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error was coming because I used echo=F instead of echo=FALSE. F or T are considered as symbols and hence it creates issue.
Here is why F (or T) is a symbol (see ?is.symbol to know what a symbol is):

```
> str(alist(warning = F)) 
List of 1 $ warning: symbol F > str(alist(warning = FALSE)) List of 1 $ warning: logi FALSE
```

Comment: Wow, what a difficult bug to track down. Thank you for posting this answer. For anyone else reading, I saw this same error caused by "eval=F" in the annotations to my rmarkdown code chunks, rather than in the code itself. Watch out for that!