# how to load() and view() a function argument [i.e. function(x) ] in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble with `load` and `view`. I want to write functions that will allow me to do a whole lot of things by just naming what will be a dataframe

```
# example dataset
n <- 3
dat <- data.frame(
  c1=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
  c2=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE)   )
save(dat, file = "dat.rda")
# my function to load and view a dataframe with a single call
jtest <- function(x) {
load(    paste0(      x,".Rda")    )
View(    paste0(      x,".Rda")    )
}

jtest("dat")
```

My desired output would be that it loads up the dataframe `dat`

```
  c1 c2
1  1  3
2  1  5
3  5  5
```

Instead, when I run `jtest("dat")` it opens something with the same icon as a dataframe named `paste0(x, ".Rda")`, one column named `V1`, one row named "1", and a cell value of `dat.Rda`:
V1
1 dat.Rda

I've looked at a couple of options, trying to wrap variously in `as.name()` or use `assign()` but I must be really thick because I'm not getting it!

Ref:
[Error in object[seq_len(ile)] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635748/error-in-objectseq-lenile-object-of-type-symbol-is-not-subsettable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` needs a R object, you are passing character value to it. You can use `get` to get R object from it's name.

```
jtest <- function(x) {
  load(paste0(x,".Rda"))
  View(get(x), title = x)
}

jtest("dat")
```